# Webcam software that takes pictures at regular intervals

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a time-lapse video with webcam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50339/how-to-make-a-time-lapse-video-with-webcam)

I have just moved from my old webcam to a Logitech QuickCam Pro 4000 (or so). Yes, I know it's an old webcam. I just replaced an older one, a QuickCam Chat. With the old one, I used camorama with a very specific incantation to make the gods of V4L happy.

With the old QuickCam, I had two main uses. The first was that it was a rear-view mirror that I had set in a window in the corner of my monitor, so the motion would tell me if people come up behind me. The second is to take a picture every 20 minutes or so, so I can keep track of my beard growth, etc. Both of these were very easy to set, once you 1) found the magical incantation to appease the V4L gods and 2) set the color correction so you didn't look quite so blue.

I now have the Pro working. It talks to VLC. It talks to Cheese. It talks to the GMail Chat website. What it does not do, that I can tell, is work with camorama.

I don't mind this. Honestly, software that's been abandoned for 4 years in the state it is, that's well worth escaping. But I can't just keep Cheese open because it can't be set to take pictures. And I can't just set a crontab with  `streamer -c /dev/video0 -b 16 -o outfile.jpeg` because then I lose my rearview mirror.

Do I have to look into rolling my own webcam software here? Forking Cheese to get my scheduled picture-taking? Or is there a webcam program that does what I want that I just don't know about yet?