# Extracting images from video at 1 minute intervals

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I would like to extract images from a video `Exp01.avi`. The video is 25 minutes long. I want the images to be extracted from the video at 1 minute intervals.

I have tried these commands, but they didn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 1  -t 00:01:00 -f image image%02d.png
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 1/1440 -f image image%02d.png
```

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer for [How to make a stop-motion or time-lapse video with webcam?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50339/how-to-make-a-stop-motion-or-time-lapse-video-with-webcam), you might get some good ideas :)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Extracting images from video in 1 minute intervals](http://superuser.com/q/557006/110524).

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 0.01  -t 00:01:00 -f image2 image%02d.png
```

`-r` is what you need to change. `-t` is how long your video will go on ;)

Hope to be helpful