# How can I extract an image from a particular time of a video in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, video

I am looking for a command line option.

For example, if I have the video `sample-video.mp4`, and I want to generate an image file `sample-image.jpg` from the video at time 00:00:26, what command should I give?

Also, it would be very helpful if you can explain in detail what the function of every argument of the command is.

Comment: According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260968/extracting-images-from-video-in-1-minute-intervals?rq=1) and its answers `ffmpeg` seems to support filenames for the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `mplayer` (from package `mplayer`, not installed by default):

```
mplayer -vo jpeg -ss 00:00:26 -frames 1 sample-video.mp4
```

This will create the file `00000001.jpg` so you have to rename it. As far as I know there's no way to specify a filename.

`-vo jpeg` means you want JPEG output, `-ss 00:00:26` seeks to the given position, `-frames 1` means to process one frame and then quit.

Comment: What is the advantage of getting more than 1 frames? Will those be copies or each frame will differ by a second?

Comment: Images created from more frames will differ by fractions of a second. Tjhe exact value depends on the video.

Comment: @Sonevol The frame exactly at 0:00:26 may not be *exactly* what you want. You may want to take the ~50 frames between 0:00:25 and 0:00:27 (or even just 3-4 frames around the 0:00:26 mark) and then browse through them to pick the best one.

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Possible also to output to png with something like: `-vo png:z=9` with the -z setting specifying compression level. For jpeg you could also add in a quality setting: `-vo jpeg:quality=100`. But your answer is great as it is already :)

Answer (score 15):

You can use **ffmpeg**

```
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -ss 26 -i sample-video.mp4  -t 1 -f image2 anyfilename.jpeg
```

- **-loglevel** set the logoutput to *quiet* because ffmpeg is very chatty
- **-ss** is seek (in seconds, i.e. where you want to take the snapshot)
- **-i** input video file
- **-t** timeframe of the snapshot (in seconds)
- **-f** filetype

You can also play around with the options, like control quality of the jpeg output `-q:v <linear integer 1-10>` or resolution  `-s 480x300` .

Some more ideas [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

---

**VLC Method**

```
cvlc sample-video.mp4 --start-time=26 --run-time=1 --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --aout=dummy  --scene-ratio=24 --scene-prefix=sample-image --scene-replace vlc://quit
```

- **cvlc** - because its command-line and we don't want any windows opening. 
  also, this means we can run it without X11.
- **--start-time=26** - is the exact position of the snapshot in seconds
- **--run-time=1** - how long the video will "play" in seconds. We play it for one second to make a screenshot of this second
- **--rate=1** when to take the screenshot. This basically means "every second" and is useful, if you have longer files, to take a screenshot every 60 seconds or every 5 minutes
- **--video-filter=scene** tell VLC that we want to take screenshots
- **--vout=dummy** no output for video on X11, we don't need it
- **--aout=dummy** no output for audio, we don't need it
- **--scene-ratio=24**  we tell VLC that there are approx 24 frames per second
- **--scene-prefix=sample-image**  the filename of your screenshot
- **--scene-replace**  replace any files that are called like your screenshot `sample-image.png` with your current screenshot. If you omit this, VLC will start numbering the screenshots
- **vlc://quit**  quit vlc once we are finished

Complete documentation [here](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)

Comment: What do you mean by chatty? And I want a snapshot at the 26th second.  So why specify timeframe by -t. I am taking image not video.

Comment: "Chatty" because ffmpeg prints over 40 lines of log output with this command, like the current version, setup type and information about the input video file - which is uninteresting for you. For your purpose you can probably omit "-t 1". Seems the default is one second or a fraction of that, which is fine for the screenshot. The nice difference is the possibility to define the output filename and tweak quality/resolution, etc